# Как подключить memcached?

Tags: php, memcached

Добрый день.

Подключен memcache. Работает.
А как подключить memcached? Подскажите, пожалуйста, пример.
Там надо в апаче прописывать или в php.ini? 
У меня пишет, что его нет:

> Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not
> found

Спасибо.

Comment: Вы его установили?

     apt-get install php5-memcached

Обратите внимание на `d` в конце.

Как правило memcached расширение устанавливается корректно и прописать дополнительно ничего не нужно. Всё добавляется автоматически:

![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/zku9fWx.png

Comment: Установить расширение Memcached, ubuntu-пакет php5-memcached. Ваш капитан О.

Пользуясь случаем - особой разницы в них нет.

Comment: @romeo, вы правы - есть художники, а есть маляры...

Comment: php-pecl-memcached

Comment: Читал, что memcached быстрее, чем memcache. Захотелось посмотреть. )) Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин Сомнительное утверждение. memcached имеет множество "обвесов", к примеру, CAS токены для версионирования ключей, multi-методы. Впрочем, это всё экономия на спичках. Кстати, [вот сравнение](http://ruhighload.com/index.php/2010/05/07/memcache-vs-memached-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-php/)

Answer (score 1):

Оставлю небольшую инструкцию по установке `memcache` т.к тема похоже актуальна:

1. Обновляем репозиторий:

   > apt-get update
2. Устанавливаем демон `memcached` и модуль:

   > apt-get install memcached php5-memcached
3. Проверяем запуск демона:

   > netstat -tap | grep memcached
   >
   > > tcp 0 0 localhost:11211 *:* LISTEN 21448/memcached
4. Перезапускаем вебсервер

Для `apache2`:

> service apache2 restart

Для `php-fpm`:

> service php5-fpm restart